# Trying to understand textbook exercise question regrading RSA

Tags: rsa

I am preparing for the final exam in my Data Security class so I am trying to read and understand the [textbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0133354695)'s exercise questions. Any hint would be great.

**Question** (Exercise 9.14 of textbook):
[image]

[image]

**Observation**:
Similar to $RSA$ decryption that $e.d = 1$, we to find some number $r$ such that $E*r = 1$ so that $(m^E)^r \ (mod \ N) = m$. But what should that $r$ be? Any hint would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that Alice uses $D' = E^{-1}(\varphi(N) - 1)$ with $E^{-1}$ the inverse of $E$ modulo $\lambda(N)$.
The question uses a very specific definition of $D'$, which requires the assumption that $E$ divides $\varphi(N) - 1$. But since such an $E$ is necessarily coprime to $\varphi(N)$, it is a special case of the more general definition of $D'$ provided above.

So we must find some number $E'$ such that
$$E' E^{-1}(\varphi(N) - 1) \equiv 1 \pmod {\lambda(N)}$$
Now note that $E' = -E$ is a solution because $\varphi(N) \equiv 0 \pmod{\lambda(N)}$, so we have

$$m^{-ED'} \equiv 1 \pmod N$$.

So given $c = m^{E}$, compute $c^{-D'}$ to obtain $m$ again. Either you first take the inverse, or you just use $\lambda(N) - D'$ as the exponent.